# How to clean old persistent znodes (Zookeeper)

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am using zookeeper for distributed locking. The use case require taking lock on hierarchical namespaces and thus we are using persistence znodes. We are using apache-curator for this.

The problem is that znode count keeps on increasing and performance is affected by this. **Is there any solutions through which we can cleanup old znodes by filter on update time?**

There is new node type: **container** which is introduced in [zookeeper 3.5.1-alpha](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2163) which will be a possible solution for this problem but stable version is not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper hasn't such function , maybe you can do a job task to clean the expire node .For example : insert the expire time with path to db , then scan db .